# Is it a good idea to have a big set/list as column in `Scylla DB`?

Tags: nosql, scylla

Is it a good idea to have a table in `Scylla DB` with column type `set` with couple of thousands elements in it, e.g 5000 elements?

In Scylla documentation it's stated that:

> Collections are meant for storing/denormalizing a relatively small amount of data. They work well for things like “the phone numbers of a given user”, “labels applied to an email”, etc. But when items are expected to grow unbounded (“all messages sent by a user”, “events registered by a sensor”…), then collections are not appropriate, and a specific table (with clustering columns) should be used. ~ [[source](https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/cql/types.html#noteworthy-characteristics)]

My column is much bigger than "the phone numbers of a given user", but much smaller than “all messages sent by a user” (column set is going to be 'frozen', if that matters), so I am confused what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main downside of having a large individual cell - frozen set, string, or a even an unfrozen set - is that the CQL API does not give you an efficient way to read or write only part of that cell. For example, every time you want to access your set, Scylla will need to read it entirely into memory. This takes time and effort. Even worse, it also increases the latency of *other* requests because Scylla's scheduling is cooperative and does not switch tasks in the middle of handling a single cell because it is assumed to be fairly small.

Whether or not 5,000 elements specifically is too much or not also depends on the size of each element - 5,000 elements of 10 bytes each totals 50K, but if it's 100 bytes each they total 500K. A 500K cell will certainly increase tail latency noticeably, but this may or may not be important for your application. If you can't think of a data model that doesn't involve large collections, then you can definitely try the one you thought of, and check if the performance is acceptable to you or not.

In any case, if your use case involves **unbounded** collections - i.e., 5,000 elements is not a hard limit but some sort of *average*, and if in some rows you actually have a million elements, you're in for a world of pain :-( You can start to see huge latencies (as one single 1-million-cell row delays many other requests waiting in line) and in extreme cases even allocation failures. So you will somehow need to avoid this problem. Avoiding it isn't always easy - Scylla doesn't have a feature that prevents your 5,000-element set growing into a million-element set (see https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/10070).

Answer (score 1):

If your set is frozen, you can be a little more relaxed about it. This is because ScyllaDB will not have to break it into components and re-create it so often as it does with non-frozen sets.

So if you're sure the frozen set won't be larger than a megabyte or so, it will be fine. For simple read/write queries it will be treated as a blob.